# Thousand of session (sess_*) files in tmp directory

Tags: server, cron

I have 3 VPS with similar setup that hold news/blogging wordpress websites.
In 2 of them i keep getting thousand sess_* files in /home/user/tmp directory.

I had to set a cron job to delete these files in 2 of those VPS's and can't understand what is the problem and why i get this issue in only 2 of them and not in the third one.

All garbage collection variables (session.gc_*) are similar in all 3 installations.

I really have googled for hours to find a solution, but i can't find anything that works.

I am not an ubuntu specialist, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you all.

Comment: Hello. Do you know which application writes these files? By default such directory `$HOME/tmp` is not available. Probably this topic could help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13776/201297

Comment: Thank you for your responce. There is no simple way to know this. I tried what is mentioned there but the diles have 0 bytes and probably are created in very short time for me to find out with lsof command.

Comment: I read few posts about similar issue, it looks like the problem is due to some php code that writes these session files. I have VPS with several WP sites and I didn't found such `sess_*` files anywhere on it. Probably on these two VPS of yours there are installed some WP plugin that writes these files.

Comment: The only plugin i find common in the 2 VPS's but not on the third one (that doesn't have the same problem , although the setting is the same) is Contact Forms 7, which is very strange to cause such problems.